# Alternative to PropertyPathMarker in NEST elasticsearch client library

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch.net

Im just kick starting my project to migrate elasticsearch from 1.7 to 7.x. As part this, changing my client library NEST to latest version.
Im extensively using PropertyPathMaker class in query generation logic. I can't seem to find what is that I need to use in latest version of NEST.

Can any of you help on this.

Below is the sample code i have problem with.

```
List<KeyValuePair<PropertyPathMarker, ISort>> BuildSortDetails(Dictionary<string, string> sortDetails,
                                                                    SortOrder defaultSortOrder,
                                                                    bool IsCaseInsensitive = false,
                                                                    Dictionary<string, ListedBoolFilterContainers> nestedFilterDetails = null,
                                                                    bool preserveSortOrderValue = false);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Field`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/field-inference.html) replaces `PropertyPathMarker` in NEST 2.x onwards.

Comment: Thanks Russ, Will give it a try.

Comment: Also, Is there some reference where I can find what changed in NEST 1.7 to 2.x ?  I'm ' having tough time to find like 'SearchSourceDescriptor' and 'QueryDescriptor' and the list goes on..

Comment: Take a look at the 1.x -> 2.x breaking changes: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/nest-breaking-changes.html